# ConTeXt: Page numbering in words for spanish

Tags: numbering, tex-core, context

So I tried to hack [the macro](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Page_numbering_in_words) given in the ConTeXt wiki to write pagenumbering in words in spanish, my native language. Things were great until I had to reach the 100th page. ConTeXt claims when compiling, but I don't know how to fix the macro so it can write hundred-numbers.

'Cien' is 100 for spanish. 'Ciento uno' for 101, 'ciento dos' for 102 and so (You can see a more detailed example [here](http://spanish.about.com/cs/forbeginners/a/cardinalnum_beg.htm)). So basically I need to prepend the word 'cien' for each word number from 1 to 99 to write the one-hundreds, 'doscientos' for the two-hundreds... [Here](http://pastebin.com/1DH4PUDP) is my dirty hacked version of the macro (you may save it as 'numstr.tex' for compiling), and a minimal example as follows:

```
\input numstr
\defineconversion[numstring][\numstr]
\setupuserpagenumber[numberconversion=numstring]
\starttext
\dorecurse{100}{\recurselevel\page}
\stoptext
```

I'm such a noob with TeX and I cannot figure out how to do this. Could you TeX/ConTeXt masters give me a clue? Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using MkIV? In that case, you can simply adapt the `verbose.english` function from [core-con.lua](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/core-con.lua) to Spanish (The function is written in Lua, so it should be easy to modify it). If you send the resultant code to the context mailing list, then it will be added to the core as well.

Comment: Yeah, actually I'm using MkIV. But I don't know anything about Lua (seems pretty easy but I don't know how to test any modification... running `lua core-con.lua` from my shell?). I guess I should start translating the `words` array... Can you give me a clue? I need this ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: It will be best to send the email to the context mailing list asking to extend thr `words` conversion to Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

ConTeXt provides a conversion `words` (and `Words`) for converting numbers to words. This converts the number into words in the current language (currently one English and Spanish are supported).

For example:

```
\starttext

\startitemize[words,fit,board]
  \item One 
  \item Two 
  \item Three
\stopitemize

\mainlanguage[es]
\startitemize[words,fit,board]
  \item One 
  \item Two 
  \item Three
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

gives

[image]

See `core-con.lua` on how to add support for other languages.