# How to add support for another language (German) to the Words conversion in ConTeXt?

Tags: luatex, context, conversion, lua, context-lmtx

I would like to implement support for another language (German) for the conversion methods `words` and `Words` for converting numbers to words in *ConTeXt*. Having read the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82722/context-page-numbering-in-words-for-spanish) I thought, this would be rather straightforward. However, I recently switched to ConTeXt version *LMTX* and found that all changes that I added to the code in `core-con.lua` were simply ignored.

Then I checked the directory tree and found that `core-con.lua` resides in `<installationpath>/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv`, so I though that it would be as simple as adding my customizations in `.../base/mkxl`. But there don't seem to be any *Lua* files anywhere... In fact, I performed a file search in the whole installation tree and found that the only file, in which the `verbose` and `translate` functions were defined (in English, Spanish and Swedish at the time of this writing) was the aforementioned `core-con.lua` -- which seems to be ignored.

Can anybody help me understand, what I am missing here? Is there any place, where I can add my customizations?

Comment: Changing in these files usually requires you to regenerate the format? Did you do that?

Comment: Could you please explain, what you mean by this? These are just plain text files... do they need to be *compiled* somehow?

Comment: Yes, you run `context --make` to generate new format files. This is done automatically for you when there is an upgrade.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. That explains a lot. My customizations seem to be picked up now. :) Would you like to post this as an answer so that I can "accept" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do changes in these files you have to run

```
context --make
```

to regenerate the format. This is merely a memory dump, mostly for speeding things up.

I suggest that you then send the patched file to the context mailing list, so that it can be added for all to use.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, as soon as I have something usable I will send it to the mailing list.